# Geometry Nodes - subdivide Extrude

Tags: geometry-nodes, subdivision-surface, extrude

is it possible to subdivide extrude node ? do you have any suggestions? thanks.
example :

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: _Subdivide Mesh_ node?

Comment: Will it always be an extrusion of individual faces?

Comment: 1) i fix the image. 2) i need subdivisions like the photo. 3)  i need this in general,it was just an example.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

one possible way:

[image]

Nodegroup:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but i need something more general.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way, I think it's fairly robust.. the steps in the GN group are:

- Stash face normals
- Extrude the mesh once
- Duplicate the extrusion (Stashing dupe indices) and move duplicates out along stashed face-normal by a multiple of dupe index
- Merge all by distance
- Scale 'Top' faces (including internal) by a multiple of (shifted) dupe index.
- Delete all extrusion 'Tops' except the last, to get shot of internal faces

[image]

Current inputs:

- Extrusion height
- Number of divisions
- Tip scale

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you, nice approach.